# Joining intervals in perl

Tags: perl, intervals

First let me show an example:

I have one set of intervals like

```
[1,4],[5,15],[16,20]
```

and the other one like

```
[2,3],[6,14]
```

and I want it become one set like

```
[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,15],[16,20]
```

I am not sure what this operation is called though, forget me if the title was misleading. Is there a CPAN module with I can use or is it better to come up with my own solution? Is there a general well known algorithm?

Comment: [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) ??

Comment: Are you just taking a set of tuples, sorting the elements of the set and then retupling them?

Comment: I didn't look it on it like that but you are right, this should be easy enough to implement. If you can post you comment as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Is the combination of inputs `[1,4],[5,15],[16,20]` and `[3,6]` possible? If so, I think both answers are wrong.

Comment: It is, why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: What result would you expect if the lists were `[1,7],[2,15],[16,6]` and `[3,20],[5,4]`?

Comment: the are no overlapping intervals in one set, in my set of inputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `pairs` function from List::Util is a possible solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'pairs';

my @a1 = ([1,4],[5,15],[16,20]);
my @a2 = ([2,3],[6,14]);

my @new = pairs sort {$a <=> $b} map {@$_} @a1, @a2;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@new;
```

This prints

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2
          ],
          [
            3,
            4
          ],
          [
            5,
            6
          ],
          [
            14,
            15
          ],
          [
            16,
            20
          ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

my @set1 = ([1,4],[5,15],[16,20]);
my @set2 = ([2,3],[6,14]);

# Make the tuples into an unsorted list
my @nums = ();
foreach my $tuple (@set1,@set2) {
    foreach my $num (@{$tuple}) {
        push @nums, $num;
    }
}

# Sort the list
my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @nums;
print "@sorted\n";

# Retuple
my @finalset = ();
while(my @tuple = splice(@sorted,0,2)) {
    push @finalset, \@tuple;
}
print Dumper(\@finalset);
```